# How can you pass a vector<pair<int, int> > into a function?

Tags: c++, vector, std-pair

If I try to declare the function as `void some_function(vector<pair<int, int> > theVector)`, I get an error (presumably from the comma after "`pair<int`."  Any ideas on how I can pass this vector with pairs into a function?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

void someFunc(int x, int y, vector<pair<int, int> > hello);

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 5;

    vector<pair<int, int> > helloWorld;
    helloWorld.push_back(make_pair(1,2));

    someFunc(x,y,helloWorld);
}

void someFunc(int x, int y, vector<pair<int, int> > hello)
{
    cout << "I made it." << endl;
}
```

Error: 'vector' has not been declared

Comment: conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >' requested

Comment: It sounds like an error in the way you're calling it to me.

Comment: Can you paste enough code for us to replicate the error?

Comment: The above, for example, won't work if I try it like that.

Comment: Imagine that the function is defined with something.  If I call it exactly like that, with #include<vector> it still doesn't work.

Comment: Let's not imagine... please post the actual code.

Comment: vector is nor declared in the current namespace, and you're not using std:: to indicate one

Comment: just add `using std::pair;` and `using std::vector;` after the `include` section

Answer (score 4):

You failed to include `<utility>`, which defines `std::pair`, **and** you're using `vector` and `pair`, instead of `std::vector` and `std::pair`.

All of the standard template library is inside the namespace `std`, so you must prefix types from the STL with `std`, like `std::vector`. An alternative would be to add `using std::vector;` after you include `<vector>`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have provide full namespace for vector, pair, make_par, they are from std namespace:

```
void someFunc(int x, int y, std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > hello);

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 5;

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > helloWorld;
    helloWorld.push_back(std::make_pair(1,2));

    someFunc(x,y,helloWorld);
    return 0;
}

void someFunc(int x, int y, std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > hello)
{
    std::cout << "I made it." << std::endl;
}
```

Side note: you could pass vector to someFunc by reference, this will elide unnecessary copy:

```
 void someFunc(int x, int y, const std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >& hello);
                              ^^^                                   ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you included `<vector>` and `<utility>`?
You should use the `std::` namespace on both `vector` and `pair`.

eg.
`void some_function(std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > theVector)`

edit: Of course you generally shouldn't pass in a vector by value, but by reference.

eg.
`void some_function(std::vector< std::pair<int, int> >& theVector)`

Answer (score 0):

I chekced your code you just have to add the `std` namespace right below your `#include`. And you don't need to add `#include <utility>` it can work without it.
`using namespace std`